# git-ftp issue: "pathspec '' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Tags: git, ftp, git-ftp

In order to sync a Git with my FTP, I setup git-ftp as explained in [this manual](https://git-ftp.github.io/).

However, I keep getting following error in the Mac OSx console:

```
usr:web usr$ git ftp init
usr:web usr$ error: pathspec '' did not match any file(s) known to git.
usr:web usr$ fatal: Can't access remote 'ftp://mydomain.com:***@ftp.myprovider.com', exiting...
```

I did not forget to select the folder "_site" in my main git folder as the path to sync:

```
usr:web usr$ git config git-ftp.syncroot _site/
```

After checking, the config file also reads

```
[git-ftp]
    user = mydomain.com
    password = longpassword
    url = ftp.myprovider.com
    syncroot = _site/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

- Do you set your real account data into **[git-ftp]** section?

  - If so -- try to delete *syncroot* and wite full path (starts with
    domain name or ip) into  **url** row.

Then try to connect for example by upload command:

```
git ftp init
```

-- and look at a text returned by this command into console.

**LOOK:** Your git config file (path  *.git/config* from project root) may be like this one ([example with 2 servers](http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/8132)):

```
[core]
    bare = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    logallrefupdates = true
[git-ftp "test"]
     user = df836as
     url = "92.51.82.51/spc/public_html"
     password = dfgd34rg34g
[git-ftp "prod"]
     user = b44539_qwe
     url = "free.gett.com/"
     password = df33334g
```